# Beamer: Add small text in frametitle

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I am using Beamer and wanted to add small text in the heading of the frame like the below image ('Pre-proposal work')[image]

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Would this have to hold for *all* slides, or just a particular one? What theme are you using? Can you create a small, minimal document we can use as foundation for providing you the help you need/want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\raisebox{distance}{text}`

The `\raisebox` command is used to raise or lower text. The mandatory argument specifies how high the text is to be raised (or lowered if it is a negative amount).

[image: e]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\hfill Today's talk: Part 1 of 3 \hspace*{2em}\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\bfseries\tiny Pre-poposal work}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This version uses `\llap` to overlap the centering.  Note that beamer already adds `\hfill` to both sides, shrinking the available space, hence the `\hbox to \textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\hbox to \textwidth{\hfill Today's talk: Part 1 of 3 \hfill\llap{\bfseries\tiny Pre-poposal work}}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```